# How to change list of str into list of floats

Tags: python, string, list, floating-point

```
def avg_temp_march(f):
    """(file open for reading) -> float

    Return the average temperature for the month of March
    over all years in f.
    """
    file = open(f, 'r')

    file.readline()
    file.readline()
    file.readline()

    lines = file.read().strip().split('\n')
    file.close

    for line in lines:
        month = line.split('    ')[0:]
        march = month[2]
```

The table is:

```
['24.7', '25.7', '30.6', '47.5', '62.9', '68.5', '73.7', '67.9', '61.1', '48.5', '39.6', '20.0']
['16.1', '19.1', '24.2', '45.4', '61.3', '66.5', '72.1', '68.4', '60.2', '50.9', '37.4', '31.1']
['10.4', '21.6', '37.4', '44.7', '53.2', '68.0', '73.7', '68.2', '60.7', '50.2', '37.2', '24.6']
['21.5', '14.7', '35.0', '48.3', '54.0', '68.2', '69.6', '65.7', '60.8', '49.1', '33.2', '26.0']
['19.1', '20.6', '40.2', '50.0', '55.3', '67.7', '70.7', '70.3', '60.6', '50.7', '35.8', '20.7']
['14.0', '24.1', '29.4', '46.6', '58.6', '62.2', '72.1', '71.7', '61.9', '47.6', '34.2', '20.4']
['8.4', ' 19.0', '31.4', '48.7', '61.6', '68.1', '72.2', '70.6', '62.5', '52.7', '36.7', '23.8']
['11.2', '20.0', '29.6', '47.7', '55.8', '73.2', '68.0', '67.1', '64.9', '57.1', '37.6', '27.7']
['13.4', '17.2', '30.8', '43.7', '62.3', '66.4', '70.2', '71.6', '62.1', '46.0', '32.7', '17.3']
['22.5', '25.7', '42.3', '45.2', '55.5', '68.9', '72.3', '72.3', '62.5', '55.6', '38.0', '20.4']
['17.6', '20.5', '34.2', '49.2', '54.8', '63.8', '74.0', '67.1', '57.7', '50.8', '36.8', '25.5']
['20.4', '19.6', '24.6', '41.3', '61.8', '68.5', '72.0', '71.1', '57.3', '52.5', '40.6', '26.2']
```

I have figured out how to get the 3rd item of each list (temperature for the month of march) but don't know how I convert them into floats so that I can get the sum

Comment: `file.close` doesn't close the file.

Comment: Where is the return statement in the function?

Comment: I didn't put this in my answer because it is unrelated to the question, but you might want to look into the `with` keyword for opening files.  It is cleaner and auto-closes the file for you when done.

Answer (score 9):

Simply use `map`:

```
>>> l = ["1.2", "2.4"]
>>> print map(float, l)
[1.2, 2.4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your current code you could just use `float`

```
for line in lines:
    month = line.split('    ')[0:]
    march = float(month[2])
```

I think more pythonic way would be

```
sum([float(x.split(' ')[2]) for x in lines])
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension will do the trick:

```
myListOfFloats = [float(i) for i in myListOfStrings]
```